# How to Construct Proper Spherical Coordinates in Minkowski Spacetime?

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems

In $n$ dimensional Euclidean space, we only need one radial coordinate, and $n-1$ angular coordinates, where one ranges from $[0, 2π)$ and the rest range from $[0, π]$

Spherical Minkowski coordinates are introduced as a cylyndrical like system, with a spherical spacial part and a cartesian time part.

Are there coordinates for Minkowski space that are only radial+3 angular coordinates?

I'm sure one of the angles would be strange, and r would lose its simple interpretation, but it doesn't seem impossible to do.

Comment: You can certainly use 4D hyperspherical coordinates, but the problem is that they don't play well with the metric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are roughly Rindler coordinates. The downside is you need to use different coordinate systems to describe future-timelike, spacelike, past-timelike and null 4-vectors.

Future-timelike ($c=1$ units):
\begin{align*}
  t &= \tau\ \cosh\eta, \\
  x &= \tau\ \sinh\eta\ \cos\theta, \\
  y &= \tau\ \sinh\eta\ \sin\theta\ \cos\phi, \\
  z &= \tau\ \sinh\eta\ \sin\theta\ \sin\phi.
\end{align*}
Here $\eta$ runs over all real numbers.
But $\tau$ has the interpretation of proper time

For spacelike 4-vectors you can swap $\sinh$ and $\cosh$ (and maybe rename $(\tau,\eta)$ as $(\rho, \tau)$ or something).
For past-timelike you need a minus sign in the expression for $t$.
I either can't remember how to deal with null vectors or I never knew.

Comment: I assumed the "r" coordinate would look something like the proper time, thanks!

Comment: What are the domains of theta and phi? 2 π and π respectively? Or the reverse?

Comment: Hmm, you should get every combination of signs once. So (eta, theta, phi) from 0 to (infinity, pi, 2 pi) respectively should work. Or both signs for eta and theta up to pi/2. There might be other ways. You can also permute the expressions for x,y,z to make it look more like the usual spherical coordinates.